# Cross correlation of gaussian signals with its mean signal gives non-gaussian distributed scores

Tags: normal-distribution, mean, lognormal-distribution, cross-correlation, convolution

The following is my question:
I have signals that contains noise, they are of the following form see the figure below.[image: Figure 1]. Then I take the mean signal of all these signals (identical in length and shape). Just adding up the signals and dividing by the number of signals see [image: Figure 2].

Following that I take the cross correlation of all these signals with their mean signal. The following histogram is the distribution of the resulting cross correlation scores.

I thought this would be gaussian distributed, but it seems log normal.
I know log normal is created by multiplication of gaussian distributions, but as the mean is the same for every convolution, how can this be log normal? Due to reputation restrictions I cannot post a 3rd picture but trust me it is either lognormal or log logistic.

If I did something wrong in the structure of this question, please feel free to give some feedback, I will change it as quickly as possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Can you edit your question so that the image embedded in the post instead of us having to click on the link to see it?

Comment: Sure! I'll get right to it

Comment: Voila, should be fixed now. Still new to these commands.